# Is the address of an array equal to its first element in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof, implicit-conversion

Assume this array:

```
int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Here `arr` has two purpose - it is the name of the array and it acts as a pointer pointing towards the first element in the array, so `arr` is equal to `&arr[0]` by default.

My questions is, what about `&arr`? is this also equal to the above?

Comment: Yes, the *value* of all three the same. The type of `&arr[0]` and the *pointer* `arr` is *decaying* to is the same (`int *`). But the type of `&arr` is different (`int (*)[5]`).

Comment: And what would the types be?

Comment: See the updated comment

Comment: so `&arr` is `pointer to the whole array` rather than its first element?

Comment: Yes. It is a *pointer to array of 5 ints*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array is in fact an extent of memory. So the address of an extent is the address of the stored array in this extent and of its first element.

As a result an array designator used in expressions with rare exceptions is converted to pointer to its first element.

Using the example provided by you

```
int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

these expressions `&arr` and `&arr[0]` have the same value but are of different types.

The expression `&arr` has the type `int( * )[5]` while the expression `&a[0]` has the type `int *`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    printf( "&arr == &arr[0] is %s\n", 
            ( void * )&arr == ( void * )&arr[0] ? "true" : "false" );

    printf( "sizeof( *&arr )  = %zu\n", sizeof( *&arr ) );          
    printf( "sizeof( *&arr[0] )  = %zu\n", sizeof( *&arr[0] ) );            
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
&arr == &arr[0] is true
sizeof( *&arr )  = 20
sizeof( *&arr[0] )  = 4
```